# Translating functionality between java and python

Tags: java, python, quantitative-finance

Hi I have the following function in java which seems to work as anticipated in calculating the [maximum drawdown](http://ycharts.com/glossary/terms/max_drawdown).

The function is the following:

```
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("########");
        double max_dd = 100;
        for(double t0:returns.keySet()){
            for(double t1:returns.keySet()){

                if(t1>t0){
                    double r = returns.get(t1)/returns.get(t0)-1;
                    if(r<max_dd){
                        max_dd = r;
                        System.out.println(df.format(t1) +"," +df.format( t0) + "," + max_dd + "," +returns.get(t1) + "," + returns.get(t0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I get one result here.

Then I run the following function in python:

`pd` below is pandas, as is common notation.

```
def max_dd_(ser):
    max2here = pd.expanding_max(ser)
    dd2here = ser - max2here
    return dd2here.min()
```

And the result is a much different number.

The data is coming from the same source file, and is of the format: `Date,Wealth` (Eg: 2014-01-1,12.5)

I trust the java code due to the simplicity and transparency, but prefer python due to its conciseness.

Any pointers on what I may be missing here?

Comment: you should give more clues about `pd` object, `expanding_max` method, `dd2here`

Comment: @marmeladze see above. pd is pandas.

Answer (score 0):

The math was different. Py function should be:

```
def max_dd_(ser):
    max2here = pd.expanding_max(ser)
    dd2here = ser / max2here - 1
    return dd2here.min()
```